# How do I split a string into words?

Tags: c, arrays

I have a file that has 3 columns and data in it. I have no column headings, just the data.
My file is something like this:

[image: Data]

Now I want to read the data in the file, and draw a bar chart with it. But I'm having trouble reading from the data. My logic was store the file contents in an array, split the array with `\n` so that you store each line into another array. Then split the new array with  to signal a different column.

This is my function which takes the data file as a parameter:

```
#include "visualiser.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include  <unistd.h>
#define LSIZ 128
#define RSIZ 10
void passFile(char *arr);

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    initInterface("silver","blue");
    if(argc <2){
        passFile("data-file.txt");
    }
    if(argc == 2){
        passFile(argv[1]);
    } else {
        printf("Invalid arguments");
        exit(0);
    }
    return 0;
}

void passFile(char *arr){
    char line[RSIZ][LSIZ];
    char fname[20];
    int i = 0;
    int tot = 0;
    int waitingTime = 0;
    int finishTime = 0;
    FILE *fptr = NULL;
    fptr = fopen(arr, "r");
    while(fgets(line[i], LSIZ, fptr)){
        line[i][strlen(line[i]) - 1] = '\0';
        i++;
    }
    tot = i;
    printf("\n The content of the file %s  are : \n",arr);
    for(i = 0; i < tot; ++i){
        char str[18];
        strncpy(str,line[i],18);
        const char s[2] = "\n";
        char *token;
        /* get the first token */
        token = strtok(str, s);
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
            char str1[18];
            int arrivalTime;
            int serviceTime;
            strncpy(str1,token,18);
            const char s1[2] = " ";
            char * pch;
            // printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str1);
            pch = strtok (str1,s1);
            sscanf (line[i], "%17s %d %d", str1, &arrivalTime, &serviceTime);
            appendRow(str1); //get the first column name
            appendBar(i+1,serviceTime,"black"," ",0);
        }



        /* walk through other tokens */
        while(token != NULL ) {
            // printf( " %s\n", token);
            token = strtok(NULL, s);
        }

    }
    printf("\n");
    // printf("The file has %d lines", processCount);   
    sleep(100);
    waitExit();
    fclose(fptr);
}
```

Now I get bars drawn to the graph. However, they are duplicated and the values are all wrong. For example, first bar should have a length of 3 but this is the output:

[image: Graph output]

Comment: Please show the input data **as text**  formatted as a code block. Please add enough code and remove unnecessary parts to allow compiling and running your program. (Add a `main` function or make a `main` from `passFile`, remove all calls to uninteresting functions like `waitExit`, `appendRow` etc.)

Comment: give me a second

Comment: Okay getting better progress with this. I'll update the post just now

Comment: @user3121023 i've posted changes and new output

Comment: Please post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There is no way to debug your code without making assumptions as to what parts which aren't included here do - which will most likely be false.

Comment: For a general treatment of the topic of splitting a line into "words", see [these class notes](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx10h.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider reading a single line.
Parse that line with `sscanf`. The return from `sscanf` will be the number of items scanned. If three items are scanned, process them.
`fgets` will return NULL at the end of the file and terminate the loop.

Here is code that does this:

```
void passFile(char *arr){
    char line[LSIZ];
    char fname[20];
    char str[18];
    int arrivalTime;
    int serviceTime;
    int i = 0;
    FILE *fptr = NULL;
    if ( NULL != ( fptr = fopen(arr, "r"))) {
        while ( fgets ( line, LSIZ, fptr)){
            if ( 3 == sscanf ( line, "%17s %d %d", str1, &arrivalTime, &serviceTime)) {
                appendRow ( str1);
                appendBar ( i + 1, serviceTime, "black", " ", 0);
                i++;
            }
        }
        sleep(100);
        waitExit();
        fclose(fptr);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```